# How to set up vscode: protocol to open links in VS Code on Linux?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, url-scheme

I downloaded and ran VS Code from a tarball, which does not set up the `vscode:` protocol binding. So when I installed the Cody AI extension for VS Code, it prompted me to sign in, and I signed in with GitLab in Firefox, but when Firefox tried to redirect me back to VS Code using the `vscode:` protocol, it didn't know how to because the protocol wasn't registered.

How can I register the protocol manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the `.desktop` file template by going to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/resources/linux/code-url-handler.desktop and clicking the download icon in the top bar of the file.
2. Edit the file you just downloaded. Replace `@@NAME_LONG@@` with "VS Code". Replace `@@EXEC@@` with the full path to the `code` executable on your system. Replace `@@ICON@@` with some random application icon, e.g. `firefox` (it doesn't really matter). Replace `@@URLPROTOCOL@@` with `vscode`.
3. Very important - do not skip this step, which I couldn't find documented anywhere else, or it won't work! **Move the file into `~/.local/share/applications`** and remove any `.download` extension if your browser has added it - the file should now have a `.desktop` extension.
4. Type `xdg-settings set default-url-scheme-handler vscode <your .desktop filename>`. **Do not provide an absolute path or you will get a cryptic error about invalid application name.**

Now try logging in to the extension again and it should all work. However, I did restart VS Code and Firefox, so you might need to do that as well.

Comment: Perhaps it should have been obvious, but xdg-settings may be run as any old user, and -must- be run as the user who needs the protocol to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Robin. Building on that, if you just want to one-off open a link in vscode, you can run `vscode --open-url $URL_FROM_LOGIN_PAGE` where you use your browser devtools to pull the `Location` header from the response in the login page and use that as `$URL_FROM_LOGIN_PAGE`. Example filled in command: `vscode --open-url 'vscode://Codium.codium?windowId=1&provider=email&email=rick@sanche.ez&token=abc...'`